# Entity Framework Core: how to get records from start index x with limit of y?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Example

- Page 1: start index 0, limit 50
- Page 2: start index 49, limit 50
- Page n: start index x, limit y

Is this right?

```
context.Products.Where(condition).Skip(x).Take(y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get :

- 1st page you need to skip 0 and take 50
- 2nd page you need to skip 50 and take 50
- ...
- Nth page you need to skip (N-1) * 50 and take 50

So the correct syntax will be:

```
// pageIndex => the page index. page starting at 1.
// pageSize => the page size.
context.Products.Where(condition).Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

If you page start at 0, so you will do:

```
context.Products.Where(condition).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```